# jqGrid JSON add data

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

Let's say I have a perfectly fine JSON serialized string, like so:

```
{"Page":0,"Total":0,"Records":0,"Rows":[{/*blah*/}]}
```

This isn't returned by a particular URL, it's just sitting there, happy as it can be (harcoded). How do I add it to jqGrid? I've tried every conceivable variation of the `loadComplete` function or a `addJSONData` variant, latest:

```
 loadComplete: function(){ 
   var mygrid = jQuery("#grid")[0];
   var o = eval("(" + {"Page":0,"Total":0,"Records":0,"Rows":[{/*blah*/}]} + ")");
   mygrid.addJSONData(o.result);
}
```

but it won't work. It has worked when I've returned the JSON by a URL, however. Am I missing something when I use:

```
 dataType:"json", 
 url: "/SomePageThatDoesntDoAnything"
```

I have a sneaky feeling it might have to do with having to reload the grid. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

check this link: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data

you need to set up the following jqgrid properties:

```
datatype: "jsonstring",
datastr : JSON.stringify(JSON_OBJECT, function replacer(key, value){return value});, //
```

JSON.stringify function is defined on the [json.org](http://json.org) site.

Comment: @Blazemonger Can you boil this down a bit?  I have a string that returns whether a key has a checked value or not, how would I put that into your formula?  my json looks like this : {"User1":"Checked","User2":""} etc.  Thanks for any help, been trying to figure this out for days!  BTW, for further info, I have some strings, and some not strings in the same grid(or trying to do so)